# (SSG-WSG) Mismatch in return values for Retrieve Courses API and Course Details API

Tags: api

The return values for `statisticsSummary` and `support > period` are different for the same course reference number:

- For `statisticsSummary`, Retrieve Courses is returning null but data exists in Course Details.
- For `support > period`, the `from` and `to` in Retrieve Courses are reversed.

### Retrieve Courses

```
# https://public-api.ssg-wsg.sg/courses/directory?pageSize=10&page=0&keyword=coc%20bim

{
  "data": {
    "courses": [
      {
        ...
        "referenceNumber": "ITE-T08GB0022B-01-DM1003CS",
        ...
        "statisticsSummary": null,
        ...
        "support": [
          {
            ...
            "period": {
              "from": "2021-03-31T00:00:00Z",
              "to": ""
            },
          }
        ],
        ...
      },
```

### Course Details

```
# https://public-api.ssg-wsg.sg/courses/directory/ITE-T08GB0022B-01-DM1003CS

{
  "data": {
    "courses": [
      {
        ...
        "referenceNumber": "ITE-T08GB0022B-01-DM1003CS",
        ...
        "statisticsSummary": {
          "courseReferenceNumber": "ITE-T08GB0022B-01-DM1003CS",
          "pageViewCount": 85
        },
        ...
        "support": [
          {
            ...
            "period": {
              "from": 20180524,
              "to": 20210331
            },
            ...
          }
        ],
        ...
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This Shan here, from the SSG-WSG API Platform team.

For the return value of “statisticsSummary”, please use the value returned in the Course Details API.

For the Retrieve Courses API, I understand that the return value for “period” has been rectified. You may wish to try again.

Thank you for sharing your feedback with us!